# Firefox Auto Download OFX

Tags: python, selenium, mime-types, ofx

My script automatically pulls files down from a website using selenium. I've been able to get it to work well for nearly all files except a couple like .OFX files.

Here's where I set the Firefox profile:

`profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-excel,text/csv,application/vnd.intu.qfx,application/csv,application/qif,text/qif,application/qbo,text/qbo,text/plain,application/txt,application/vnd.intu.qbo,application/x-ofx,application/ofx,text/ofx,text/xml')`

I've included everything I can think of (including application/octet-stream) but still I get a popup in firefox for .OFX files - what gives?

Comment: How about `application/download` or `binary/octet-stream` or `application/binary` or `application/x-unknown`?

Comment: Added all those, still getting pop-ups..

Comment: Thanks. Could you share or point to this OFX file somehow?

Comment: Can you tell the "Content-Type" header in the request (Developer tools / Network tab)?

Comment: What is an `OFX` file? I searched [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html) and I couldn't find it in the MIME-Types.

Comment: OFX - open financial exchange, common file format for banks to use in documenting transactions